# PNGj, metadata doesn't get saved

Tags: java, png, metadata

I'm trying to save metadata, but it doesn't get saved, an i don't get any errors either.
The image get saved correctly.
I'm using the PNGJ library.

Reading metadata, (and the image) works correctly, and i'm checking with imagemagick.

The code is:

```
ImageInfo imi = new ImageInfo(size.x, size.y, 8, true);
PngWriter pngW = new PngWriter(outputStream, imi);
pngW.setCompLevel(compressionLevel);
pngW.getMetadata().setText(PngChunkTextVar.KEY_Title, "My image");

ImageLineInt iline = new ImageLineInt(imi);

for (int row = 0, c = 0; row < pngW.imgInfo.rows; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < imi.cols; col++) {
        int r = image[c++] & 0xFF, g = image[c++] & 0xFF, b = image[c++] & 0xFF, a = image[c++] & 0xFF;
        ImageLineHelper.setPixelRGBA8(iline, col, r, g, b, a);
    }

    pngW.writeRow(iline);
}
pngW.end();
```

**Why isn't the metadata get saved, or why don't i get an error message?**

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure the metadata is not writen? Bear in mind that (unless told otherwise) chunks are written as late as possible (in this case: the text chunk will be written after the IDAT chunks. You can check with http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't now that! that was actually the problem in my program. The thing that threw me of is that imagemagick won't show the chunks that i write with PNGJ, but it show the chunks written with GIMP or TweakPNG. Is there any way to read metadata in advance? should i just open (and close) another PNGreader?

Comment: "imagemagick won't show the chunks that i write with PNGJ" why? because they're after the IDAT? that would be a bug. you can verify that, TweakPNG lets you move a chunk. " Is there any way to read metadata in advance?" I don't understand what that means.

Comment: I would like to read the metadata, before the pixels because it can have significant information how my software should use the data. But as far as i understand i have to call pngReader.end() to read the chunks after the data, so if the input is an inputStream that can't be rewind than i have to have two of them, or buffer the data to an array, which is sub-optimal. As far as Imagemagick goes, it doesn't show the data even if i move it to the top of file with tweakpng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PNG format, textual chunks have no restriction about its position in the chunks sequence: they can be placed after the IDAT chunks (pixels data). That's because it's assumed that textual metadata should not be needed (or influence) the image display.

The PngWriter for the [PNGJ](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/) library puts the metadata chunks in a queue, to be written (by default) as late as legal/possible. In practice, this means that Textual chunks will be written after the IDAT chunks. If you don't want this, you should first ask yourself if you really want to put image information (that you need to display the image) in a textual chunk, that sounds broken. Anyway, if you want to force the textual chunk to be written as early as possible, simply set the priority to true: [PngChunk.setPriority()](https://pngj.googlecode.com/git/site/apidocs/ar/com/hjg/pngj/chunks/PngChunk.html#setPriority(boolean))

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! My intentions where to use png and not a proprietary format to store all the data with the image i need, and make it simple to open with other software.