# Android pngj with Bitmap and custom header

Tags: android, png, metadata

I'm trying to use the PNGJ library to add custom meta data, tEXT

In Android I do the following

```
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    output.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

Is it possible to do something like this in PNGJ

```
     Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     //Add custom meta-data here
     //Save the PNG file with PNGJ here using output
```

What I've done so far is this,

```
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
ImageInfo imi = new ImageInfo(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 16, true); 
PngWriter png = new PngWriter(stream, imi);

png.getMetadata().setDpi(100.0);
png.getMetadata().setTimeNow(0);
png.getMetadata().setText(PngChunkTextVar.KEY_Title, "testing");
png.getMetadata().setText("Custom Key", "some text");
//Not sure how to connect the bitmap above to the PngWriter here
```

2nd method, add the tag later

```
public void addTag(File orig, File dest, boolean overwrite) {
    PngReader pngr = new PngReader(orig);
    PngWriter pngw = new PngWriter(dest, pngr.imgInfo, overwrite);
    pngw.copyChunksFrom(pngr.getChunksList(), ChunkCopyBehaviour.COPY_ALL_SAFE);
    pngw.getMetadata().setText("appkey", "I'm value", true, false);

    for (int row = 0; row < pngr.imgInfo.rows; row++) {
        ImageLineInt line = (ImageLineInt) pngr.readRow(row);
         pngw.writeRow(line, row);
    }
    pngr.end();
    pngw.end();
}
```

Now when I try to get it with this I got nothing

```
PngReader reader  = new PngReader(new File(fileName1));

 Log.d("pngkey", "value is: " + reader .getMetadata().getTxtForKey("appkey"));
```

Please note that when I checked the png with the below and I do see the new tag added

pngcheck -c -v -t image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do the conversion yourself.
The most simple (if not most efficient) way is:

- instantiate a [ImageLineInt](http://hjg.com.ar/pngj/apidocs/ar/com/hjg/pngj/ImageLineInt.html) (or ImageLineByte)
- loop over each row of the Bitmap, calling `Bitmap.getPixels()` to store the pixels in the line, packed as ints ([Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)), in a `int[]` array
- fill the ImageLine, pixel by pixel, using ImageLineHelper.setPixelRGBA8(), (or manually)
- Write the ImageLine to the png.

That's basically all. You must first decide if you are generating an image with Alpha or not (it seems yes). Also, I'm not sure why are you putting 16 for bitdepth, it should almost surely be 8. Tell me if you need more help.

---

Update: 
Regarding your modified question:

```
PngReader reader  = new PngReader(new File(fileName1));
String txt= reader.getMetadata().getTxtForKey("appkey");
```

This will not found the metadata if it's placed after the pixels data (IDAT chunks). That's because, at that point, you've not yet read the full image. In that case, `getMetadata()` will only read the metadata before the image pixels 
(it won't read the full image, because the philosophy of PNGJ is not to read the image in memory, but let the user do it progressively). If you want to read only the metadata and discard the image pixels, then you can loop over all the image rows, or, better, call [readSkippingAllRows()](http://hjg.com.ar/pngj/apidocs/ar/com/hjg/pngj/PngReader.html#readSkippingAllRows()) and end the reading of the image.

You can also force, at writing time, the position of textual chunks, to be placed before the pixels data, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871638/pngj-metadata-doesnt-get-saved).

Comment: Dude, you're awesome.

Comment: @AdroidFreak were you able to successfully create the PNG? I'm getting this exception when trying the steps suggested by leonbloy: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null reference used for synchronization (monitor-enter) at java.util.zip.Deflater.end(Deflater.java:541)